# redirect in Spring MVC with AngularJS

Tags: spring, angularjs, model-view-controller, tiles2

I am newer in the angularJS. I'm working with spring mvc 3.1.1.RELEASE and tiles 2.2.2.
I want to display a hosts' list of client in the second page.

There's where I'm at:

client.jsp :
[...]

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col"><spring:message code="clients.name" /></th>
                        <th scope="col"><spring:message code="clients.email" /></th>
                        <th scope="col"></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="client in page.source">
                        <td class="tdClientsCentered">
                            <input type="hidden" value="{{client.id}}" />
                                <a href="<c:url value='/protected/hosts/{{client.id}}'/>" >
                                {{client.name}}
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td class="tdClientsCentered">{{client.email}} </td>
                      </tr>
                </tbody>
</table>
```

[...]

So when the user click in the link (user) the page of "hostsList" will display.

hosts.jsp :

```
<div class="row-fluid" ng-controller="hostsController"> 
[...]
<div>
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col"><spring:message code="host.name" /></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="host in hosts">
                        <td class="tdHostsCentered"><input type="hidden" value="{{host.id}}" /> {{host.name}} - {{host.addressip}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

</div>
```

[...]

tiles.xml:

```
<definition name="master.page" template="/public/template/master.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/public/template/header.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/public/template/footer.jsp" />
</definition>

<definition name="hostsList" extends="master.page">
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/protected/hosts/hosts.jsp" />
</definition>
```

HostsController.java

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public ModelAndView listAll(@PathVariable("id") int id, @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = DEFAULT_PAGE_DISPLAYED_TO_USER) int page,Locale locale) {
    createListAllResponse(page, locale, id);
    ModelAndView modelAndview = new ModelAndView("hostsList");
    HostListVO hostListVO = hostService.findAll(page, maxResults, id);
    modelAndview.addObject(hostListVO);

    return modelAndview;
}
```

hosts.js

```
"user strict";

function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
} 

km.app = angular.module('km', []);

angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    var app = document.getElementById('km');
    angular.bootstrap(app, ['km']);
});

km.app.service('Utils', function ($http, $q) {
    var self = this;
});


function GlobalCtrl($scope, $location, GlobalSettings, $http, $routeParams, $timeout, Utils) {    
}

km.app.controller('hostCtrl', ['$scope', 'Utils', function ($scope, Utils) {



    $scope.hosts = []; 

    var dataset = [];

try {
        Utils.GetValidations(getParameterByName('id')).then(function (data) {
            $scope.hosts = data.hosts;
        });
    } catch (err) {
        alert(err);
    }
} ]);
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd ">

    <!-- Spring servlet that will handle the requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/spring.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Map all requests to the DispatcherServlet for handling -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Spring basic configuration -->
    <!-- Bootstraps the root web application context before servlet initialization -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <!-- needed for ContextLoaderListener -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/spring.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Spring security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- Encoding helper filter -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- Encoding utility -->
    <jsp-config>
        <jsp-property-group>
            <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
            <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
            <trim-directive-whitespaces>true</trim-directive-whitespaces>
        </jsp-property-group>
    </jsp-config>

</web-app>
```

I get :

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'hostsList' in servlet with name 'dispatcher'
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1204)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1005)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:952)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why would you use AngularJS if you use Spring MVC to give a model and a view and use jsp? Maybe you can make your Spring MVC a REST-interface and use AngularJS for all your client-side code.

Answer (score 0):

in your host controller try
ModelAndView modelAndview = new ModelAndView("/hostsList"); instead of just "hostList"